# When I pull an order meta does it pull all order meta in database query or just the one requested

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, woocommerce, metadata

I have over 25 meta in the WooCommerce order. Sometimes I need just 1 meta value, sometimes, I need 10 or more of them.

I pull the order meta as below.

`get_post_meta( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )`

When I need 1 meta value. I do once.
When I need 10, I pull each one by it's name by 10 times above statement.

My question is when I run get_post_meta once, wordpress makes one database query to the server?
When I pull other 10 metas on different custom admin page, it makes 10 database queries to the server?

OR on single get_post_meta Wordpress pulls all meta related to that post and puts into cache, then somewhere else when I pull other 10 metas for the same order, it uses from cache, not additional database queries.

The reason I am asking, I can store all meta in single key and save using json_encode as well. But not sure whether it would be optimal to store separate or combined. As when I need 1 meta, I will still need to pull it and use json_decode which will use compute power in addition to database query to the server.

I hope the question is clear, let me know if any clarification needed.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

The function `get_post_meta` is defined in the WP Core `/wp-includes/post.php` is accessing the post meta data from the cache. If it's not in the cache, it reads from table and set to the cache. So next time, it will be reading from the cache. you can see the main section below.

```
$meta_cache = wp_cache_get( $object_id, $meta_type . '_meta' );

if ( ! $meta_cache ) {
    $meta_cache = update_meta_cache( $meta_type, array( $object_id ) );
    if ( isset( $meta_cache[ $object_id ] ) ) {
        $meta_cache = $meta_cache[ $object_id ];
    } else {
        $meta_cache = null;
    }
}
```

You can see the code in the file, `wp-includes/meta.php` around line 577

Comment: Thank you for the code location, I analyzed the code around that in meta.php. It seems, WP caches all meta even if only 1 meta key is requested for the first time for the particular post_id(object_id). Did I reach right conclusion?